# Rancher - standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "permission denied"

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, rancher

Actually I'm trying to deploy Kubernetes via Rancher on a single server.

I created a new Cluster and added a new node.

But after a several time, an error occurred:

> This cluster is currently Provisioning; areas that interact directly with it will not be available until the API is ready.
>
> [controlPlane] Failed to bring up Control Plane: Failed to verify healthcheck: Failed to check https://localhost:6443/healthz for service [kube-apiserver] on host [172.26.116.42]: Get https://localhost:6443/healthz: dial tcp [::1]:6443: connect: connection refused, log: standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "permission denied"

And when I'm checking my docker container, one of them is always restarting, the *rancher/hyperkube:v1.11.3-rancher1*

I'm run `docker logs my_container_id`

And I show `standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "permission denied"`

On the cloud vm, the config is:

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Docker Version: 18.06.1-ce
Rancher: Rancher v2

Do you have any issues about this error ?

Thank a lot ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I called the vm sub-contractor and they created a vm with a nonexec var partition.

After a remount, it's worked.

Answer (score 0):

What is your type of architecture?

Please run:

```
uname --all
```

or

```
docker info | grep -i "Architecture"
```

to check this.

**Rancher is only supported on x86.**